# Apache Ofbiz 13 remove a hot-deploy component

Tags: apache, ofbiz

So I'm started using Apache Ofbiz (13) and I came across their beginners tutorial [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/OFBiz+Tutorial+-+A+Beginners+Development+Guide+for+13.07%2C+14.12+and+15.12#OFBizTutorial-ABeginnersDevelopmentGuidefor13.07,14.12and15.12-CustomizingUserInterface). Within the tutorial they mention a command:

```
ant create-component
```

Which is used to create a component in `hot-deploy`, so my question is what is the command to delete a component which you have created?

I've tried:

```
ant remove-component <component_name>
```

and,

```
ant delete-component <component_name>
```

I can't find any documentation in regards to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no corresponding Ant target to remove a component. Just delete the component folder and the entry in the hot-deply ofbiz-component.xml.

If you start with OFBiz, I recommend to use trunk or the 16.11 release. Release 13 is not supported and maintained anymore.